# Convert ICU4C byte to java char

Tags: java, unicode, java-native-interface, icu

I am accessing an ICU4C function through JNI which returns a UChar * (i.e. unicode character array).... I was able to convert that to jbyteArray by equating each member of the UChar array to a local jbyte[] array that I created and then I returned it to Java using the env->SetByteArrayRegion() function... now I have the Byte[] array in Java but it's all gibberish pretty much.. Weird symbols at best... I am not sure where the problem might be... I am working with unicode characters if that matters... how do I convert the byte[] to a char[] in java properly? Something is not being mapped right...  Here is a snippet of the code:

---

--- JNI code (altered slighter to make it shorter) ---

```
static jint testFunction(JNIEnv* env, jclass c, jcharArray srcArray, jbyteArray destArray) {

    jchar* src = env->GetCharArrayElements(srcArray, NULL);
    int n = env->getArrayLength(srcArray);

    UChar *testStr = new UChar[n];
    jbyte destChr[n];

    //calling ICU4C function here    
    icu_function (src, testStr);   //takes source characters and returns UChar*

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        destChr[i] = testStr[i];   //is this correct?

    delete testStr;
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(destArray, 0, n, destChr);
    env->ReleaseCharArrayElements(srcArray, src, JNI_ABORT);

    return (n); //anything for now
}
```

-- Java code --
    string wohoo = "ABCD bal bla bla";
    char[] myChars = wohoo.toCharArray();

```
byte[] myICUBytes = new byte[myChars.length];
int value = MyClass.testFunction (myChars, myICUBytes);

System.out.println(new String(myICUBytes)) ;// produces gibberish & weird symbols
```

---

I also tried: System.out.println(new String(myICUBytes, Charset.forName("UTF-16"))) and it's just as gebberishy....

note that the ICU function does return the proper unicode characters in the UChar *... somewheres between the conversion to jbyteArray and Java that is is messing up...

Help!

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice - I just spent considerable time answering your other duplicate, only to find out today that your problem is already (apparently) resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
destChr[i] = testStr[i];   //is this correct?
```

This looks like an issue all right.

[JNI types](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html):

```
byte   jbyte    signed 8 bits
char   jchar    unsigned 16 bits
```

[ICU4C types](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/umachine_8h.html#a6bb9fad572d65b305324ef288165e2ac):

> Define UChar to be wchar_t if that is
>   16 bits wide; always assumed to be
>   unsigned.
>
> If wchar_t is not 16 bits wide, then
>   define UChar to be uint16_t or
>   char16_t because GCC >=4.4 can handle
>   UTF16 string literals. This makes the
>   definition of UChar platform-dependent
>   but allows direct string type
>   compatibility with platforms with
>   16-bit wchar_t types.

So, aside from anything `icu_function` might be doing, you are trying to fit a 16-bit value into an 8-bit-wide type.

If you must use a Java byte array, I suggest converting to the 8-bit `char` type by transcoding to a Unicode encoding.

To paraphrase [some C code](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2010/04/i18n-comparing-character-encoding-in-c.html#I18N2010_CHAR_C):

```
UChar *utf16 = (UChar*) malloc(len16 * sizeof(UChar));
//TODO: fill data
// convert to UTF-8
UConverter *encoding = ucnv_open("UTF-8", &status);
int len8 = ucnv_fromUChars(encoding, NULL, 0, utf16, len16, &status);
char *utf8 = (char*) malloc(len8 * sizeof(char));
ucnv_fromUChars(encoding, utf8, len8, utf16, len16, &status);
ucnv_close(encoding);
//TODO: char to jbyte
```

You can then transcode this to a Java String using `new String(myICUBytes, "UTF-8")`.

*I used UTF-8 because it was already in my sample code and you don't have to worry about endianness. Convert my C to C++ as appropriate.*

Comment: Thank you!!! That makes sense. I changed everything to jcharArray and everything works now.

p.s: I don't have enough reputations to give you thumbs up but I will as soon as I have enough :) A new user here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using ICU4J?

Also, when converting your bytes to a string, you will need to specify a character encoding. I'm not familiar with the library in question, so I can't advise you further, but perhaps this will be "UTF-16" or similar?

Oh, and it's also worth noting that you might simply be getting display errors because the terminal you're printing to isn't using the correct character set and/or doesn't have the right glyphs available.

Comment: ICU4J is not an option due to its size (5MB+) and the project already has ICU4C and JNI integeration. I did try the ICu4J however and it worked well but I am trying to achieve the same thing using JNI and ICU4C.

Comment: Regarding the terminal issue, nope... I did take that into consideration as it works well when I tried the ICU4J so the glyphs are there